# Mensagem de erro após abrir arquivo Excel gerado por uma aplicação

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Tenho uma aplicação que lê um arquivo `xml`, pega os dados e passa pra um arquivo no formato `xls`. Porém quando vou abrir o arquivo que foi gerardo aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia me explicar a causa desse erro?

Comment: Pode postar o código? Sem ele fica difícil ajudar

Comment: O código é um pouco "Gigante". Mas acho que consegui resolver, vi alguma coisa sobre mudar pro formato de xlsx. Vou fazer mais alguns testes

Comment: Se for muito grande, recomendo colocar no paste bin e passar o link. Se conseguir a solução não deixe de colocar a resposta. =)

Comment: Vou colocar no pastebin.

Comment: Classe que gera o relatório: http://pastebin.com/NDmQ4LHs

Comment: Método: http://pastebin.com/HwzPamj4

Comment: Olhei aqui na documentação que a classe XSSFWorkbook  gera arquivo .xlsx e HSSFWorkbook  gera arquivo .xls. Faz alteração da extensão ai no seu código para ver se funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A POI eh dividida em bibliotecas **H** e **X**.

Bibliotecas **H** (HSSF, HWPF, HSLF) produzem documentos em formato **.doc**, **.xls** e **.ppt**, enquanto bibliotecas **X** (XSSF, XWPF, XSLF) produzem os formatos **.docx**, **.xlsx** e **.pptx**.

Como voce esta usando a XSSF, alterar a extensao do arquivo salvo para **.xlsx** resolve o problema.

Comment: Se eu quiser xls tenho que procurar as bibliotecas H?

Comment: Correto. As duas bibliotecas sao bem parecidas, porem a X (mais nova) tem mais recursos. Voce precisa realmente produzir .xls? O formato .xlsx ja tem 8 anos de idade.

Comment: Sim, pois alguns clientes ainda usam versões antigas do office :/